# main navigation menu disappear after adding jquery source file

Tags: plugins, jquery, jquery-ui

I have created a new page on my website: https://membership.gai-edu.eu/country-qualification/ and added jquery source file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

which is on 1034 line of code and after that my main navigation menu disappears completely for some reason. The menu is fully visible on other parts of the website. I need to keep that jquery file in order for some other page parts to work for me.

What I can do to keep that Jquery file there and make navigation visible again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is already being included on the page, so you don't need to include it again.

I'm assuming your adding that because you want to run the JS below it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#countryChooser").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        var selector = "." + $(this).val();
        $('.box').not(selector).hide();
        $(selector).show();
        } else {
        $(".box").hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

If that's the case, remove the additional call to load jQuery, then change all the `$` to `jQuery`.

For example...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#countryChooser").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() !== "") {
        var selector = "." + jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('.box').not(selector).hide();
        jQuery(selector).show();
        } else {
        jQuery(".box").hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: You don't actually have to change all of the `$` to `jQuery`.  Should just be able to use:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and the rest can stay as is.

Comment: That should work as well

Comment: thank for help, it worked just fine as per your instructions